# What is the difference between post-/pre- sampling, aliasing, filtering and processing?

Tags: sampling, antialiasing, filtering, post-processing

What is the difference between post-/pre- sampling, aliasing, filtering and processing?
How do the terms post-/pre-**aliasing**, post-/pre-**processing**, post-/pre-**sampling** and post-/pre-**filtering** relate to each other?

On many websites/articles these terms are often used 
without clearly stating the differences. 
Some even use them interchangeable, all tough they
seem to have different meanings.

It would be very helpfull mentioning where in the 
**graphics-pipeline** these steps happen 
(e.g. before/while/after rasterization, etc.),
and what the refence points for the name suffixes are
(pre … before what?, post … after what?).

Comment: This question is far too big to be handled in our format. Many of those terms have nothing to do with the others, and many of them are used in different ways in different contexts. Overall, your question asks far too many things, to the point where any complete answer would probably have to be a chapter or two from a graphics textbook.

Comment: Could you link to the relevant articles so that we could see the context? Ideally provide relevant excerpts along with the links. I should also mention that I disagree with Bolas' sentiment about the terms - filtering, sampling, and aliasing have clear formal and mathematical definitions and are related through Shannon's sampling theorem.

Comment: I like the idea of a basic comparison answer without going into details. That can then lead to other questions which can be linked to from the answer - the full subtleties don't all have to be present in one post.